# c++ abstract class with nested class. derived class and nested class

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested, abstract

I have the task to write own containers `Linked_list` and `Array_list`. I have one interface for them:

```
typedef int value_type;
class Container 
{
public:
        class Iterator 
        {   
        public:
            Iterator();
            Iterator(value_type* other);
            Iterator(const Iterator& other);
            Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& other);
                    ...
        };

    Container();
    Container(const Container& other);
    ~Container();   

    virtual value_type& front() const=0;
    virtual value_type& back() const=0;
    virtual Iterator begin() const=0; // 
    ...
};
```

I did derived classes Linked_list and Array_list:

```
class Linked_list:public Container 
{
public:
    long int cur_size;
    List elem;
    static Link end_;
    class Iterator: public Container::Iterator
    {
        friend Linked_list;
        Link *p;    
    };

    Iterator begin() const; //overriding virtual function return type differs ...

...
}
```

I thinks it's all wrong. should nested class `Linked_list::Iterator` be a derived class? 
Is it possible to do this, if I can't change the interface?

Comment: Are you allowed to change `typedef int value_type;` because then you could make it a template by changing it to `template <class value_type>` and changing your derived class to be specific type of the template.

Comment: Why do you think it's all wrong? The way you organised the classes seems to make sense.

Comment: I can't change this. And it's supposed that I must do it without using templates.Sorry for my English

Comment: It seems to me that it is correct, but what I don't understand is why you have a Linked_list and a Link inside Linked_list::Iterator.

Comment: The override of `begin` in `Linked_list` is not valid, because the return type is different and is also not acceptable as a covariant return type (for that it would need to be a pointer).

Comment: have you checked std::forward_list and std::array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking into account your design constraints *that you cannot use templates*, than one thing should change: add interface `IteratorImpl`. Thus you can make `class Iterator` from base `class Container` **non virtual**. It needs to be non-virtual since STL-alike iterators should have *value semantics*. See [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Idioms#Pointer_To_Implementation_.28pImpl.29) for more details how it works!

Like this:

```
typedef int value_type;
class Container 
{
    protected:
        class IteratorImpl
        {   
        public:
            virtual void next() = 0;
            virtual IteratorImpl* clone() const = 0;
            virtual value_type get() const = 0;
            virtual bool isEqual(const IteratorImpl& other) const = 0;
        };

    public:
        class Iterator 
        {   
        public:
            Iterator(IteratorImpl* impl) : impl(impl) {}
            ~Iterator() { delete impl; }
            Iterator(const Iterator& other) : impl(other.impl->clone()) {}
            Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& other) {
              IteratorImpl* oldImpl = impl;
              impl = other.impl->clone();
              delete oldImpl;
            }
            bool operator == (const Iterator& other) const 
            {
               return impl->isEqual(*other->impl);
            }
            Iterator& operator ++ ()
            {
                impl->next();
                return *this;
            }
            value_type& operator*() const 
            {
               return impl->get();
            }
            value_type* operator->() const
            {
               return &impl->get();
            }
        };
        Container();
        Container(const Container& other);
        ~Container();   

    virtual value_type& front() const=0;
    virtual value_type& back() const=0;
    virtual Iterator begin() const=0; // 
    ...
    };
```

Then in your derived just implement IteratorImpl:

```
class Linked_list:public Container 
{
protected:
    class IteratorImpl: public Container::IteratorImpl
    {
       ....
    };

public:
    Iterator begin() const { return new IteratorImpl(firstNode); }
    Iterator end() const { return new IteratorImpl(nodeAfterLastNode); }

...
};
```

These firstNode and nodeAfterLastNode are just my guess - use whatever you need to implement the IteratorImpl interface...

Comment: virtual IteratorImpl* clone() const = 0; ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz - can I ask stupid question: what should I do with functions like: Linked_list::Iterator Linked_list::erase(Iterator pos) ?

Comment: @greensher There are two methods: 1) Add to class Iterator public method getImpl() - dynamic_cast this implementation to your List implementation - then you should be able find the node to erase

Comment: @greensher Or add virtual method erase to IteratorImpl - but then you need to have reference to your container in the IteratorImpl specialization - or pass this container to method erase () - then in this method dyanmic_cast container to its derived version (List or Array)

Comment: @greensher or use double dispatch pattern - for more details ask another question (you might add this one as reference) I or somebody else could give you some more details in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should define a const_value_type to represent const value_type, and use it for the return values of the front and back virtual methods. Alternatively you can drop the const qualifiers on these methods, because having non const reference return types on const methods doesn't make sense.

Without more details on the classes, it's difficult to tell for the rest.
You could also have a look at early implementations of the STL: it's a very good way to get some insight on these topics.