# Nested iterators in abstract Container class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator

I tried to implement the solution posted here
[c++ abstract class with nested class. derived class and nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304415/c-abstract-class-with-nested-class-derived-class-and-nested-class)
by PiotrNycz. My headers look like the following:
Abstract class:

```
    #ifndef MBRINGQUEUE
    #define MBRINGQUEUE

    class MBRingQueue {
    protected:
        class IteratorImpl
        {
        public:
            virtual void next() = 0;
            virtual IteratorImpl* clone() const = 0;
            virtual int get() = 0;
            virtual bool isEqual(const IteratorImpl& other) const = 0;      
        };

    public:
        class const_iterator 
        {
        public:
            const_iterator(IteratorImpl* impl, const MBRingQueue* rq) : impl(impl) {} 
            const_iterator(IteratorImpl* impl, const MBRingQueue* rq, bool is_end) : impl(impl) {}
            ~const_iterator() {delete impl;}

            const_iterator(const const_iterator& other) : impl(other.impl->clone()) {}

            const_iterator& operator=(const const_iterator& other) {
                IteratorImpl* oldImpl = impl;
                impl = other.impl->clone();
                delete oldImpl;
            }       

            bool operator==(const const_iterator& rv) const
            {
                return impl->isEqual(*rv.impl);
            }

            bool operator!=(const const_iterator& rv) const
            {
                return !(impl->isEqual(*rv.impl));
            }

            const_iterator& operator++()
            {
                impl->next();
                return *this;
            }

            IteratorImpl* impl;
            int left;
        };

        MBRingQueue(int size);
        virtual ~MBRingQueue() {};
        virtual const_iterator begin() const=0;
        virtual const_iterator end() const=0;
    };

    #endif
```

and the class that inherits from it:

```
<pre>
#ifndef RINGQUEUE
#define RINGQUEUE

#include "MBRingQueue.h"

class RingQueue : public MBRingQueue {

protected:
    class IteratorImpl: public MBRingQueue::IteratorImpl
    {
        IteratorImpl(const RingQueue* rq);

        bool isEqual(const MBRingQueue::IteratorImpl& other) const;
        void next();
        int get();
        MBRingQueue::IteratorImpl* clone();

        const RingQueue* _rq;
        bool ring_full;
        int pos;
        int count;
    };

public:
    friend class const_iterator;

    RingQueue(int size);
    ~RingQueue();

    void push_back(int val);
    int pop_front();

    void printQueue();

    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator end() const;

private:
    int _N;
    int _act_size;
    int _start;
    int _end;
    int* _elems;;

};

#endif
```

When I now try to implement the routines:

```
    RingQueue::const_iterator RingQueue::begin() const {
        return new IteratorImpl(this);

}
```

I get the error:

> 1>  RingQueue.cpp 1>c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\project_carbos\owniterator\owniterator\ringqueue.cpp(64):
>   error C2259: 'RingQueue::IteratorImpl': Instanz von abstrakter Klasse
>   kann nicht erstellt werden 1>          aufgrund folgender Member: 1>
>   "MBRingQueue::IteratorImpl *MBRingQueue::IteratorImpl::clone(void)
>   const": ist abstrakt 1>          c:\users\michael\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2012\projects\project_carbos\owniterator\owniterator\mbringqueue.h(10):
>   Siehe Deklaration von 'MBRingQueue::IteratorImpl::clone'
>   1>c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\project_carbos\owniterator\owniterator\ringqueue.cpp(64):
>   error C2248: "RingQueue::IteratorImpl::IteratorImpl": Kein Zugriff auf
>   private Member, dessen Deklaration in der
>   RingQueue::IteratorImpl-Klasse erfolgte. 1>
>   c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\project_carbos\owniterator\owniterator\ringqueue.h(11):
>   Siehe Deklaration von 'RingQueue::IteratorImpl::IteratorImpl' 1>
>   c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\project_carbos\owniterator\owniterator\ringqueue.h(9):
>   Siehe Deklaration von 'RingQueue::IteratorImpl'
>   1>c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\project_carbos\owniterator\owniterator\ringqueue.cpp(64):
>   error C2664: 'MBRingQueue::const_iterator::const_iterator(const
>   MBRingQueue::const_iterator &)': Konvertierung des Parameters 1 von
>   'RingQueue::IteratorImpl *' in 'const MBRingQueue::const_iterator &'
>   nicht möglich 1>          Ursache: Konvertierung von
>   'RingQueue::IteratorImpl *' in 'const MBRingQueue::const_iterator'
>   nicht möglich 1>          Quelltyp konnte von keinem Konstruktor
>   angenommen werden, oder die Überladungsauflösung des Konstruktors ist
>   mehrdeutig

from the compiler (VS2012). Sorry that it is in german. Is there a way to turn the output of VS to English?.

Comment: could you post the specific error message from the compiler?

Comment: It is a german Visual Studio 2012, so I don't think it will directly help:

error C2555: 'RingQueue::begin': Der überschreibende virtuelle Funktionsrückgabetyp unterscheidet sich und ist keine 'covariant' von 'MBRingQueue::begin'

Comment: err, I cannot see anything in the linked topic that would hide the Iterator class from the base? In your example you have unrelated `const_iterator` classes in both base and derived. I am probably missing something though

Comment: Yes this was wrong. Thanks. I updated the code and the new errors.

Comment: Your `clone` method is missing the `const` specifier so the virtual function is not overridden. AFAIK, VS 2012 does support the `override` specifier which I recommend to use everytime you override a virtual function. There may be more errors than that, though.

Comment: @MadScientist
Yes this removes some errors and thanks for the suggestion with the override keyword. Yes of course there are still other erros, but I have a question on the original code (which causes also a problem in mine):

Iterator begin() const { return new IteratorImpl(firstNode); }

Does this line make sence? The return type is an object of type Iterator, while the new command returns a pointer to an object of IteratorImpl. Or do I see something wrong?

Comment: `Iterator` is implicitly constructible from `IteratorImpl*` so the compiler is allowed to construct it for you.

Comment: Even if I just copy the declaration of the Container class from the thread I get errors. E.G. in

           bool operator == (const Iterator& other) const 
            {
               return impl->isEqual(*other->impl);
            }

where IntelliSense complains about the fact that other needs to be of type pointer-to-class.

Does anyone have a running example?

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin
I don't really understand your post. And if I try to implement it the compiler complains exactly about this lines.